# error using msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail (query and body parameters must contain variables and sprocs)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How can I adjust this code so that @thequery is recognised below (it currently gives an error message like:
`Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 517
Query execution failed: Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Server CHSQL021, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'xxx'.`

```
DECLARE @thequery nvarchar(max) = 'an important message'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

        @recipients=N'me@yahoo.com;',
        @copy_recipients=N'',
        @importance='High',     
        @query = @thequery,
        @body='Body message', 
        @subject = 'Alert',
        @profile_name = 'SMTP_SQLServer'
```

@thequery is supposed to contain a text message, that's all.

Another problem is the following error message:

> Could not find stored procedure 'Databasename.dbo.Sprocname'

when I try to run the same code as above, with a slight difference:

```
@query = 'exec Databasename.dbo.Sprocname
```

, even though I know for sure that sproc exists and I can actually execute it manually.

I also get an error like

> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

when I remove the @query line completely and adjust the @body line as follows:
`@body='Body message ' + @thequery +'',`

Please advise how to correct these errors so I can use sprocs and text variables inside sp_send_mail parameters to customise body message and query.
Many thanks in advance.
Regards,

Comment: Show your entire query + stored procedure. I guess when you are passing arguments to stored procedure you concatenate string and some `'` are not escaped

Comment: Hello lad2025, the query message is simply 'xxx' for a test, and even like that it doesn't work!

Comment: As for the second tip, I get the point about the sproc containing ' and I should ask: 1) if that is the problem, shouldn't it at least recognise the sproc exists? 2) I also need to run the sproc manually in other places so is there a way to go without escaping the '`' in the original sproc? Thank you very much.